# How will i know if my curl proxy is down?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

In PHP i am using a proxy with curl with the following :

```
CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1,
CURLOPT_PROXY, ''.$current_proxy.'',
```

and i have a DB with backup proxy ip's in it, but i want to know how i can detect if the proxy has gone down so it can switch the variable `$current_proxy`.

What do you suggest for detecting if a server is down? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply check if `curl_exec()` returns `FALSE` and if it does try with a different proxy?

Comment: Just google for it: http://madppc.com/php-proxy-checker-using-curl_multi/

Comment: @EdoDodo: After you have tried all proxies (including the working ones) on a non-existant page you might come to the conclusion that this method does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can just try to connect to the proxy with [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) like that:

```
$proxy = '98.255.255.255:8080';
$timeout = 5;
$splited = explode(':',$proxy); // Separate IP and port
if($con = @fsockopen($splited[0], $splited[1], $errorNumber, $errorMessage, $timeout)) 
{
    echo 'Connection successful, PROXY works!';
} else {
    echo $errorNumber . ' ' . $errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: I have a trouble during this script execution. On "@fsockopen" - whole host is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

list.txt contains such as:

1.2.3.4:2487
123.123.123.123:3248

etc. php code like this ...

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$proxies = file("list.txt");

foreach($proxies as $proxy)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL,$proxy);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $check = stripos($page,'</html>'); // not pretty :)

        if($check > 0)
        {
            echo $proxy . " Works!";
        }else{
            echo $proxy . " Is Dead!";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl doesn't distinguish whether proxy is down or page doesn't exist (or server where this page located is down). That's why you need invent workaround by yourself. At least Daniel from Haxx AB [said it](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-05/0249.html).